# How to get .NET array type from the string "string[]"?

Tags: c#, arrays, reflection

Given the string `"string[]"` and asked to get the underlying Type for this class, one might start with:

```
private Type getTypeByName(string typeName)
{
    if (typeName.EndsWith("[]"))
    {
           return something; // But what? 
    }

    return Type.GetType(typeName);
}
```

What type is "string[]" and how does one reflect the type out of it?

Obviously there's a `System.String` type and a `System.Array` type, but I can't see how they can be reflected "together" as you would normally do for `Nullable<T>` and its T with the `MakeGenericType` method.

Any help to break the mind-loop I've gotten myself into will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What exactly is your problem? `Type.GetType` works fine:

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof(string[]));
var type = Type.GetType("System.String[]");
Console.WriteLine(type);
```

Prints:

```
System.String[]
System.String[]
```

so clearly this works as expected.

Comment: Ah, well that's fair enough.  But what if you're given "string[]" as the input instead of "System.String[]"?

Comment: @tags: well, `string` is a C# keyword, it’s not a CLR/CTS type so you can’t really expect the CLR to know about it. If you absolutely must use it, put all the C# keyword type mappings into a dictionary and use the dictionary to replace those types in your input strings.

Comment: I see, but I think I'll pass on the keyword dictionary!  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Use GetElementType() on the type:

```
string[] eee = new string[1];
Type ttt = eee.GetType().GetElementType();
```

ttt is of type String.

Answer (score 0):

Type.GetType("System.String[]") will returns the string array type. No need to check for [] in your input string.

You can verity this by checking the Type.IsArray prop.

Answer (score 0):

The type is System.String[]